# jQuery dynamic replacement with RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex

If i have `{code}{type="hey"}` and I want to replace it with `<code><pre class="hey">` how can I do it binding some method to this function:

```
$('.wysiwyg textarea').live('keyup',function(){

    wysiwyg_val = $(this).val();

    wysiwyg_val = wysiwyg_val
    .replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
    .replace(/\n\n+/g, '<br /><br />')
    .replace(/\{code\}/g,"<pre><code>")
    .replace(/\{\/code\}/g,"</code></pre>")
    .replace(/\{code}/g,"</code></pre>")
    .replace(/\{img\}/g,'<img src="http://localhost/CI_DEVBASE/img/logo.png" width="150" height="50"')
    .replace(/\{\/img\}/g,'/>');


    $('.wysiwyg-preview').html(wysiwyg_val);

  });
```

Note that I just replace `{code}` with `<code><pre>`. I would like to replace also in case of `{code}{type="$somenthing"}` to `<code><pre class="$somenthing">` where `$somenthing` is a dynamic parameter, not static.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/ may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line to the end of your replace statement -

```
.replace(/\{code\}\{type="(.*)"\}/g, '<code><pre class="$1">');
```

Comment: this is good if i do not use also the line .replace(/\{code\}/g,"<pre><code>") if i use your line and this line alltogheter in script only the first {code} is replaced then next {type=""} is not replaced ... i would like in case of only {code} replacewith <code><pre> in case of {code}{type="somenthing"} replace with<code><pre class="somenthing"> :P

Comment: Would it work if you put my line before you line? Otherwise, something like this `/\{code\}(?!\{type)/g` would match {code} blocks not followed by a {type...} block.

Comment: it works but when i remove then {type=""} it returns to <code><pre class="/code"> :P .. uhmm really hard for me :P now testing second code you gave me

Comment: omg i was mistaking man, your first answer if putted before my line of code works really great!!! sorry my mistake here :/